# ¿Como validar valores dentro de un arreglo con Validator?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validación

tengo el siguiente arreglo javascript: `arreglos_grados`, que lo implemente de la siguiente manera: `arreglos_grados = []` pero quisiera validar con el `Validator` de `Laravel 5.5` si un campo que estoy insertando en el arreglo javascript ya se encuentra registrado. 
Estoy enviando para la controller mi arreglo de la siguiente forma.

```
$('#agregar_grado').click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

           var grado = {
                id_count: 'id_' + count_grados,
                grados: $('#grados option:selected').val(),
                fecha_examen_grado: $("#fecha_examen_grado").val(),
                fecha_obtencion_grado: $('#fecha_obtencion_grado').val(),
             };

             arreglos_grados.push(grado);
             count_grados++;


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('regMiembros.agregargrados') }}',
                data: {
                    arreglos_grados.length ? arreglos_grados: null
                },

                success: function (data) {

                    if ($.isEmptyObject(data.errors)) {


                        $.smkAlert({
                            text: data.success,
                            type: 'success'
                        });

                        limpiarErroresGrados();

                        $('#lista_grados').append('<tr id="' + grado.id_count + '"><td style="text-align: center">' + $('#grados option:selected').text() + '</td><td style="text-align: center">' + $('#fecha_obtencion_grado').text() + '</td><td style="text-align: center">' + $('#fecha_examen_grado').text() + '</td><td style="text-align: center;"><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="eliminarGrado(\'' + grado.id_count + '\');"></buton></td></tr>');

                    } else {

                        limpiarErroresGrados();

                        $.each(data.errors, function (index, value) {
                            $('#_' + index).text(value);
                        });

                        $.smkAlert({
                            text: "Existen errores de validación en los grados masónicos, por favor revise ",
                            type: 'danger'
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    arreglos_grados.splice(arreglos_grados.length - 1, 1);
                    alerta(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

En mi controller tengo planteado mi `Validator` de la siguiente manera en mi funcion de la `controller`

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $attributes);
```

Como puedo hacer validaciones a elementos que están dentro de ese arreglo?

Comment: Porque no pones tus reglas de validación para poder echarle un vistazo???

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays):

> ### Validación de Arrays
>
> Validar un *array* basado en campos de un formulario no debería ser complicado. Se puede usar "dot notation"
>   para validar atributos que sean array. Por ejemplo, si la petición
>   HTTP contiene en campo `photos[profile]`, se puede validar de la
>   siguiente forma:
>
> ```php
> $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
>     'photos.profile' => 'required|image',
> ]);
> ```
>
> También se puede validar **cada elemento** de un *array*. Por ejemplo,
>   para validar que cada correo electrónico en un campo determinado del
>   array es único, se puede hacer lo siguiente:
>
> ```php
> $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
>     'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
>     'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
> ]);
> ```
>
> Del mismo modo, se puede usar el carácter * para especificar los
>   mensajes de validación en los archivos de idioma, por lo que es muy
>   fácil utilizar un solo mensaje de validación para campos basados en
>   array:
>
> ```php
> 'custom' => [
>     'person.*.email' => [
>         'unique' => 'Each person must have a unique e-mail address',
>     ]
> ],
> ```